# Laravel Advanced Search Query

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, laravel

im building a car ( car , bus ... ) seller website, i have tables like :

Brands :

```
id , name (bmw) , category (car , bus )
```

Models :

```
id , name ( 1.16, 3.20)  , brands_id
```

Car_Sale :

```
id , brand_id , model_id , price , member_id
```

Properties:

```
id , name( color , fuel ..) , value ( red , gasoline ) , car_sale_id
```

i have lots of options for properties table ( about 20 ) , what is the best way 
to handle this query ? how do you do in laravel ? should i use joins ? how can i check all of this tables and fields ?

Any ideas? Any Example Codes etc.? Thank you !

Comment: any example code or query ?

Comment: Google "SQL join" and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to model properly your [relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships), once you done with that you can use [Eloquent has many through](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#has-many-through) or [querying your relations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations).

Also if you need to join relationships with the Laravel [query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#joins) this is easy task too.

An example join:

```
 DB::table('users')
        ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
        ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
        ->select('users.id', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
        ->get();
```

I hope this can help you a bit.